# grub2win isoboot CloneZilla LiveCD unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: linux, grub, boot, iso, initramfs

Всем привет!

1. Машина Win10 Pro. С legacy bios загрузкой.
2. Установлен загрузчик grub2win. В него добавлен пункт меню isoboot CloneZilla LiveCD. iso клонзиллы лежит в папке на локальном диске (NTFS).
3. В качестве параметров загрузки установлены значения по умолчанию:

```
set isopath='/clonezilla-live-2.6.6-15-amd64.iso'
set kernelpath='/live/vmlinuz'
set initrdpath='/live/initrd.img'
set bootparms='boot=live iso-scan/filename='$isopath' noprompt noeject ---'
```

4. Попытка загрузки по этому пункту меню приводит к ошибке

```
unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

последнее успешное действие:
`fuse: init (API version 7.31)` и открывается командная строка `initramfs`.

Что я уже пробовал?

1. Попробовал использовать другие iso (debian netinstall, ubuntu mini) - загрузка проходит успешно.
2. Изменял стандатрные параметры загрузки `bootparms`. Брал набор из grub2 с самого диска. Вот полный список:

```
boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=788 ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```

Пробовал убавлять и добавлять по 1. Здесь получил важный результат - ошибка при загрузке никак не изменяется. Всегда одна и та же.

Подскажите, как можно исправить и загрузиться в LiveCD?

Comment: А с путями точно всё ок? А граб2вин умеет в нтфс? А переменную "$isopath" он точно парсит?

Comment: Да, я же попробовал другие iso, как раз чтобы исключить проблемы с путями и переменными. Переменные все парсятся, точно. В начале загрузки iso-шник подключается как loop девайс.
Я немного продвинулся, добавил debug к загрузке и получил log. Похоже, какие-то проблемы с драйверами.

Comment: Клонзилла самая свежая?

Comment: Да, в переменной `isopath` есть название файла и версия iso-шника. Похоже, что тут простых решений не будет. Сейчас пытаюсь выяснить путем дебага каждого этапа загрузки. Очень большие подозрения на ntfs, но подтвердить пока не могу их.

Comment: EFI не просто так грузится с fat32, хотя в разрабах - Майки в том числе.